# I am trying to run this function in an isolate in flutter but cant make it work, always getting the same error

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the PaletteGenetor via an isolate because it blocks my ui for a few ms/seconds.

for now i am just trying a simple example to try to make it work but for now, unsuccessefully.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(const AssetImage('assets/image-try.jpg')) // THIS WORKS
      .then((value) {
    print(value);
    paletteExpensiveFunction(imageList2).then((value) => print(value));
  });
}
```

so, first i created the palette in the init state just to show that it works (it prints the palette nicely). then i call the isolate and try to run the exact same code inside the isolate but it doesnt work! i tried many many things and cant find the solution.

```
Future paletteExpensiveFunction(List<AssetImage> assetImage) async {
  final palletteGenerator = await Isolate.run<PaletteGenerator>(
      () async => await expensiveFunction());
  return palletteGenerator;
}

Future<PaletteGenerator> expensiveFunction() async {
  final paletteGen = PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider( // THIS DOESNT WORK
      const AssetImage('assets/image-try.jpg'),
      maximumColorCount: 5);
  return paletteGen;
}
```

EDIT: (forgot to include the error. By the way, the error i belive is regarding the use of PaletteGenerator inside the isolate, i dont think the isolate knows the package or cant access it. I have tried AssetImage inside the isolate and it works, it only throws this error when including PaletteGenerator)

```
I/flutter (26622): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (26622): The following assertion was thrown while resolving an image:
I/flutter (26622): Binding has not yet been initialized.
I/flutter (26622): The "instance" getter on the PaintingBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has
I/flutter (26622): been initialized.
I/flutter (26622): Typically, this is done by calling "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" or "runApp()" (the
I/flutter (26622): latter calls the former). Typically this call is done in the "void main()" method. The
I/flutter (26622): "ensureInitialized" method is idempotent; calling it multiple times is not harmful. After calling
I/flutter (26622): that method, the "instance" getter will return the binding.
I/flutter (26622): In a test, one can call "TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" as the first line in the
I/flutter (26622): test's "main()" method to initialize the binding.
I/flutter (26622): If PaintingBinding is a custom binding mixin, there must also be a custom binding class, like
I/flutter (26622): WidgetsFlutterBinding, but that mixes in the selected binding, and that is the class that must be
I/flutter (26622): constructed before using the "instance" getter.
I/flutter (26622):
I/flutter (26622): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

stack trace looks like:

```
I/flutter (28964): #0      BindingBase.checkInstance.<anonymous closure>
binding.dart:308
I/flutter (28964): #1      BindingBase.checkInstance
binding.dart:389
I/flutter (28964): #2      ServicesBinding.instance
binding.dart:56
I/flutter (28964): #3      PlatformAssetBundle.load
asset_bundle.dart:326
I/flutter (28964): #4      CachingAssetBundle.loadStructuredBinaryData
asset_bundle.dart:272
I/flutter (28964): #5      AssetManifest.loadFromAssetBundle
asset_manifest.dart:24
I/flutter (28964): #6      AssetImage.obtainKey
image_resolution.dart:284
I/flutter (28964): #7      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey
image_provider.dart:480
I/flutter (28964): #8      ImageProvider.resolve
image_provider.dart:371
I/flutter (28964): #9      PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider
palette_generator.dart:259
I/flutter (28964): #10     expensiveFunction
top.dart:167
I/flutter (28964): #11     paletteExpensiveFunction.<anonymous closure>
top.dart:162
I/flutter (28964): #12     _RemoteRunner._run (dart:isolate:1021:47)
I/flutter (28964): #13     _RemoteRunner._remoteExecute (dart:isolate:1015:12)
I/flutter (28964): #14     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:17)
I/flutter (28964): #15     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)
```

I am trying to run a function inside an Isolate in flutter

Comment: i read it but i dont know what that means. should i create a new main function just for the isolate? i already have a main function for my flutter project that looks like this:

    void main() async {
      WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      ));
      injectorInit().then((_) => FlutterNativeSplash.remove());
      runApp(const Root());
    }

Comment: Try calling `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before `runApp();` in you `main.dart`.

Comment: I have! my main function of my flutter app looks like:

    void main() async {
      WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      ));
      injectorInit().then((_) => FlutterNativeSplash.remove());
      runApp(const Root());
    }

I am not sure the error message is being very useful in this case, not sue what else to do

Comment: and also, the PaletteGenerator with the AssetImage works when i run it outside the isolate, only inside the isolate it throws an exception!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that error message it seems that `PaletteGenerator` needs to be called from the main isolate where various parts of the Flutter engine are available. Is there a particular reason you think you need to run it in a background isolate? `PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider` returns a `Future`, which implies to me that it's already performing its work in the background anyway. If you are performing some additional expensive work with the result, then wait on `fromImageProvider` to return in the main isolate and just run your code in a background isolate:

```dart
Future<void> paletteExpensiveFunction(PaletteGenerator palette) async {
  print(palette);
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
}

class _TestPaletteState extends State<TestPalette> {
  late Future<PaletteGenerator> _palette;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _palette = PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
            const AssetImage('assets/image-try.jpg'))
        .then((value) async {
      await compute(paletteExpensiveFunction, value);
      return value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _palette,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          // Do whatever with the available palette data here
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. I implemented your advice (used BlocBuilder instead of FutureBuilder). It is working smoothly i was doing something wrong earlier which made my ui clunky but there is no need to create an isolate here. well, at least i learned about isolates